# File pattern '*.pro' was reassigned to file type 'Shrinker Config' - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've updated Android Studio to Dolphin | 2021.3.1 and now the pop-up appears with:

[Screenshot of pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtzOM.jpg)

```
File pattern '*.pro' was reassigned to file type 'Shrinker Config'
You can confirm or revert reassigning pattern '*.pro'

Actions > 
  Confirm reassign this pattern to file type 'Shrinker Config' | 
  Revert this pattern to file type 'Shrinker Config' | 
  Edit file type 'Shrinker Config'
```

Comment: Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

This message appears when you have a file with the *.pro extension in your project, and Android Studio is prompting you to confirm that you want to treat this file as a "Shrinker Config" file.

The "Shrinker" is a tool that can be used to optimize and reduce the size of your Android app by removing unused code and resources. The "Shrinker Config" file is used to specify which code and resources should be kept or removed by the Shrinker tool.

If you do want to treat the *.pro file as a Shrinker Config file, you can click "Confirm" to accept the reassignment. If you do not want to treat the file as a Shrinker Config file, you can click "Revert" to cancel the reassignment and restore the default file type for *.pro files.

It is ultimately up to you to decide whether you want to use the Shrinker tool and how to configure it. Some things to consider when deciding whether to use the Shrinker tool and how to configure it include:

- Do you need to optimize the size of your app?
- Do you have any specific requirements or constraints for the size of your app?
- Are you familiar with the Shrinker tool and how it works?
- Do you have a Shrinker Config file set up correctly?

To set up the Shrinker Config file, you will need to create a file with the *.pro extension in your project and add the necessary configuration to it. Here is an example of a simple Shrinker Config file that keeps all code and resources:

```html
-keep class * { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

You can customize this configuration to specify which code and resources should be kept or removed based on your specific needs. Use the -keep and -dontwarn directives to specify which code and resources should be kept, and use the -keepattributes directive to specify which attributes of your code should be kept. You can also use the -dontobfuscate directive to specify that the Shrinker tool should not rename your code with shorter names.